# Nmap not displaying open ports

Tags: nmap, kali-linux, network-scanners

I'm running Kali in a VM (Windows 10 host) and using nmap to scan for open ports on a vulnerable mail server. Network settings are set to host-only for both machines. I know there are more ports open then what is being shown. However, these are the only ports found after performing the attached scan. I've also tried scanning all ports with -p- but my results are the same. Any idea why?

Thanks in advance for the help.

[image: nmap scan]

Comment: Are you sure that the service / daemon is running, not firewalled and listening on all/external interfaces?

Comment: please do not post pics of text, copy/paste with code formatting

Comment: Use different scan variants: [Varients](https://nmap.org/book/man-port-scanning-techniques.html) also try using -Pn

Answer (score 2):

`Not shown: 997 filtered ports`

Because the ports that are not shown are `filtered` and not `closed`, I would guess there is a host firewall blocking access to the other ports. Turn off Windows Firewall or allow access to the required ports and you will probably be able to see them.